# Ansible - Gather Facts failed on Windows DC

Tags: windows, ansible, domaincontroller

I´m currently trying to create update Jobs for Windows Servers which mostly works. But on all my DCs (expect one, don´t know why this one is working) gathering facts failed with this error message:

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"setup": {"exception": "Access denied \r\nAt line:63 char:44\r\n+ ... e_name] = $(Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespace -ClassName $instanc ...\r\n+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Root\\CIMV2:Win3...erConfiguration:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041003,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand\r\n\r\nScriptStackTrace:\r\nat Get-LazyCimInstance, <No file>: line 63\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 142\r\n\r\nMicrosoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException: Access denied \r\n   at Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Internal.Operations.CimAsyncObserverProxyBase`1.ProcessNativeCallback(OperationCallbackProcessingContext callbackProcessingContext, T currentItem, Boolean moreResults, MiResult operationResult, String errorMessage, InstanceHandle errorDetailsHandle)", "failed": true, "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: Access denied "}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"}
```

Executing commands on those DCs are working, only gathering facts failed. On non DCs gathering facts works.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with update ansible to some > 2.9.

With ansible 2.10 or ansible4 it is working